# How to prevent immediate firing of MouseUp event in Winforms Listview when the mouse is still down?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, events

Basically if you have a standard Listview that has multi-selection turned on, the mouse up and down events work fine.

But if you turn off multi-selection and click and hold your mouse button on the Listview, it immediately fires down and then up event while the mouse button is still down.

Is there a way to prevent this? I only want the mouse up event to trigger when I release the mouse button.

Answer (score 2):

ListView mouse event processing in [WndProc](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,6248) is a bit complicated. This is what I could do by overriding `OnMouseUp` and `WndProc` to stop raisng the unnecessary `MouseUp`:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202, WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205, WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208;
    const int LISTVIEWSTATE_mouseUpFired = 0x00080000;
    FieldInfo listViewStateField;
    public MyListView()
    {
        listViewStateField = (typeof(ListView)).GetField("listViewState",
               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP || m.Msg == WM_MBUTTONUP || m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONUP) {
            var value = (BitVector32)listViewStateField.GetValue(this);
            value[LISTVIEWSTATE_mouseUpFired] = true;
            listViewStateField.SetValue(this, value);
            var x = (m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff);
            var y = (m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16) & 0xffff;
            var e = new MouseEventArgs(
                m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP ? MouseButtons.Left :
                m.Msg == WM_MBUTTONUP ? MouseButtons.Middle :
                MouseButtons.Right, 1, x, y, 0);
            OnMouseUp(e);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work better but there is some weird behaviour when I am using mouse down/move to move the form, it jumps/slides. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: I doubt that it could be related to the custom implementation. It doesn't have anything to do with form move (non-client area mouse messages). I didn't see such behavior in the example at my side.

Comment: @JoanVenge Tested with a default Form and a custom Form that intercepts the relevant `WM`-s to move and resize. Works with both without any issue.

Comment: Thx a lot guys, I will give it a try again.

Comment: @JoanVenge Did you manage to have a conclusion on this?