# Handle MouseMove, MouseDown, MouseUp Events in a ListView to drag a borderless Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I'm using `MouseMove`, `MouseUp`, `MouseDown` events to move a borderless form (as found here as an example).

It works great, but for a ListView, it only works if I click on an item (its text) in the list. It does not work if I click in the space of the ListView containing no items.

Is there a possible way to fix this?

```
private bool mouseDown;
private Point lastLocation;

private void ListView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    lastLocation = e.Location;
}

private void ListView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(mouseDown)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(
            (this.Location.X - lastLocation.X) + e.X, (this.Location.Y - lastLocation.Y) + e.Y);

        this.Update();
    }
}

private void ListView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
}
```

Comment: I imagine you would use these Event Handlers for the Container containing the ListView, whether its Form you want to move or just the Container.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do there. You handle mouse events of a ListView, apparently, but then try to move `this` (the Form) -- The ListView raises mouse events on all of it Client Area surface, no matter whether occupied by some Item or not.

Comment: ListView mouse event raising/handling is a bit strange; for example if you start a MouseDown on a non-item area, then the MouseMove event will not raise. Another example, when you start a MouseDown on an item, then release the mouse button out of the control's area, then it raises a MouseUp event the next time you move the mouse over the control, ignoring the mouse button state.

Comment: @Karlo922 I can show you some workarounds to override the default ListView mouse behavior, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48908974/3110834) or [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65873186/3110834). But the thing is, then the events will not raise for the header area, and you need more patch to make it working.

Comment: Another idea could be adding a [MessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235); but then what would be the expected behavior when the user wants to select multiple items, or when the user wants to select an item, but not move the form, and etc. In general, I feel it's not a very nice UX. I'd suggest you move a narrow move handle on top of the form, or use a custom titlebar for the form, or just let the form to be moved when the user drags the form.

Comment: @reza The user will not need to select items in the ListView. The ListView will only display items, it is not needed to be interacted by the user. So I want the user to be able to grab the window at any position to move it around. I also thought about outting another item above the list view (like a transparent box) but I cannot get the box transparent so that the list view is still readable.

Comment: @karlo922 in this case, just the `Enabled` property of the `ListView` to false, and then you don't need to handle ListView's mouse events, all the mouse events will be received by the parent control (probably your form).

Comment: @reza At first this is a good idea, but the issue is that the ListView then gets a grey background. I have a different color set to it in active state. I found some hacks to change the background color in disabled state, but then I cannot find a way to set the color of a specific item anymore. So the ListView has some items and has a black background color. If you click on a button, the software checks some things and coresponding entries in the list view will get a different text color and the checkbbox checked. All others stay with their old text color checkbox unchecked.

Comment: As Reza noted, you can implement `IMessageFilter` in your Form, to drag it no matter what Control is under the mouse Pointer. As also noted, the ListView suppresses `WM_MOUSEMOVE` when the action is initiated on a section of the Control non occupied by an Item (sub-items don't count), since it wants to draw a selection rectangle instead. You can move it clicking on an Item, or the Column Headers. Or you can patch this Control as shown in the examples. If you're OK with that, I can show you how to implement `IMessageFilter` for this.

Comment: @Jimi "If you're OK with that, I can show you how to implement IMessageFilter for this" That would be very nice!

Comment: Here you go. I hope Reza Aghaei is going to post his version. It's always nice to see what he comes up with :)

Comment: That's a really nice implementation @Jimi. For the `ListView` control, you need to set `MultiSelect = false` to make it working, even if you start dragging the control in a non-item area. (Or maybe you can find a better workaround for that.)

Comment: @RezaAghaei You mean, setting `MultiSelect = false`, you can then drag the Form clicking anywhere on the ListView? Yep, that would do it. I'll leave a note about it, it's quite possible that a *selection rectangle* is not that useful in OP's scenario. -- Thank, btw :) -- If I have some spare time, I'll see whether it's possible to avoid it (I'm the busy one this time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move a Form, clicking and dragging any Control, you can implement the [IMessageFilter Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter). You'll receive messages before they're sent to the target Control (with the option to suppress them, returning `true`).
The implementation requires that you implement [PreFilterMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.prefiltermessage).

Store the current Mouse Position when the message is `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and move the Form when it's `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, if the left Button is still pressed (the Buttons currently pressed are specified in `WParam`, see the Docs about this).

Use [Application.AddMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter) to register the class that implements the interface (the Form itself, in this case). Here, it's called in `OnHandleCreated`.
Call [Application.RemoveMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.removemessagefilter) to remove the filter. Here, called in `OnHandleDestroyed`.

Note that I've used `Capture = true;` in `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, so pressing the left mouse button and dragging, e.g., a Button Control, won't cause - in this case - a Click event.
Modify it if you don't like it.

Note:
As Reza Aghaei suggested, if you set your ListView to `MultiSelect = false`, you can then click anywhere on it to drag the Form.

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

    Point mouseDownPos = Point.Empty;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                mouseDownPos = PointToClient(MousePosition);
                break;
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if ((m.WParam.ToInt32() & 1) != 1) break; 
                Capture = true;
                var p = PointToClient(MousePosition);
                Location = new Point(Left + p.X - mouseDownPos.X, Top + p.Y - mouseDownPos.Y);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (!DesignMode) Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e) {
        if (!DesignMode) Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
    }
}
```