# How to read keystrokes in a custom Winforms control, regardless of focus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a custom component for WinForms, on which graphics are drawn.
Using the Ctrl+right/left mouse buttons, I can add or remove objects.

```cs
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
                this.EditorMode = true;
        }
        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
               this.EditorMode = false;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.EditorMode)
            {
                base.OnMouseDown(e);
                return;
            }
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                // adding new object
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                // deleting object
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine until I add something else to the custom control.
The problem is that pressing the Ctrl key will no longer be handled by the controller, but by the element on which the focus is currently set.

And I need my keyboard shortcut to work regardless of which element the focus is on...
What is the best way to do this?

I tried to redefine Processcmdkey, but it does not allow me to know if the key was pressed or released

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.ControlKey | Keys.Control))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ctrl");
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

what should I do to get the desired result: regardless of focusing on child controls, I can always add new objects to the drawing?

Comment: `ProcessKeyPreview` should do the trick

Comment: `ProcessCmdKey` doesn't notify `WM_KEYUP` and lParam's bit 30 won't help either.  As noted, `ProcessKeyPreview` instead does. Or, you could implement IMessageFilter, in case you also need to handle other messages (currently or in the future). You could implement the interface in the Form itself, see: [Handle MouseMove, MouseDown, MouseUp Events in a ListView to drag a borderless Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71143588/7444103), or using a specialized class that can be initialized, e.g., in `Program.cs`, to handle (also allow or suppress) all messages in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to implement [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in your MainForm and intercept
the `WM_KEYDOWN` message for Control-Left and Control-Right. The example below is a guideline for a `UserControl` that will add and remove buttons based on Control-Right and Control-Left respectively.

[image: add and remove buttons]

---

**Adding and Removing the MessageFilter**

The message filter will be added on the `OnHandleCreated` override and removed in the `Dispose` method of `MainForm`.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if(!(DesignMode ) || _isHandleInitialized)
        {
            _isHandleInitialized = true; ;
            Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        }
    }
    bool _isHandleInitialized = false;

    // In MainForm.Designer.cs
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

---

**Handling `PreFilterMessage`**

The MainForm will provide three `event` hooks for `ControlLeft`, `ControlRight`, and `NoCommand`. These will be fired in the `PreFilterMessage` method.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (Form.ActiveForm == this)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                    var key = (Keys)m.WParam | ModifierKeys;
                    switch (key)
                    {
                        case Keys.Control | Keys.Left:
                            ControlLeft?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                            Text = "Control.Left";
                            break;
                        case Keys.Control | Keys.Right:
                            ControlRight?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                            Text = "Control.Right";
                            break;
                        default: 
                            // Don't event if it's "just" the Control key
                            if(ModifierKeys == Keys.None)
                            {
                                Text = "Main Form";
                                NoCommand?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public event EventHandler ControlLeft;
    public event EventHandler ControlRight;
    public event EventHandler NoCommand;
}
```

---

**Responding to events in the UserControl**

The `MainForm` events will be subscribed to in the `OnHandleCreated` override of `UserControlResponder`.

```
public partial class UserControlResponder : UserControl
{
    public UserControlResponder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if(!(DesignMode || _isHandleInitialized))
        {
            _isHandleInitialized = true;
            var main = (MainForm)Parent;
            main.ControlLeft += onControlLeft;
            main.ControlRight += onControlRight;
            main.NoCommand += onNoCommand;
        }
    }
    private bool _isHandleInitialized = false;
    char _tstCount = 'A';

    private void onControlRight(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        var button = new Button
            {
                Text = $"Button {_tstCount++}",
                Size = new Size(150, 50),
            };
        button.Click += onAnyButtonClick;
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button);
    }
    private void onControlLeft(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        if(flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count != 0)
        {
            var remove = flowLayoutPanel.Controls[flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count - 1];
            if(remove is Button button)
            {
                button.Click -= onAnyButtonClick;
            }
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count - 1);
        }
    }
    private void onNoCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
    private void onAnyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainForm)Parent).Text = $"{((Button)sender).Text} Clicked";
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/application-hook-ctrl-up-down.git) this example.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I'll try it later. But I did not see how it is possible to read the release of a key, like KeyUp? And also if I want to add more buttons that could be triggered regardless of focus, for example F1, F2... then I will have to create a new event for each such button, right?

Comment: You could extend the same PreFilterMessage method to include [WM_KEYUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup).

Comment: These `F1`, `F2` buttons. Are they inside your UserControl (added in response to CONTROL+RIGHT) or on the MainForm itself?

Comment: they are also added to the usercontrol by overriding the KeyDown method.

Comment: Ok if I follow you then later when you get the chance try running the code and see if the added buttons behave the way you want them to because for sure the click event does get hooked up in the process of adding one. As you say, the focus doesn't matter and you should definitely see the response 100% if you click a button. Let me know if you see any different or if I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: for some reason, I never generate a `key` equal to `Keys.Control | Keys.Left` or `Keys.Control | Keys.Right`. When I click on any of the controls, I get `key = Keys.Control | Keys.Control Key`, and when they are released, just `key = Keys.Control`. I changed this, and added mouse click event handlers, and everything seems to be working as it should. The only thing that confuses me is how the handler is added. But I think I can put up with it.

Comment: hmm, after all, buttons like F1, F2, M and others should still be implemented in a different way. Anyway, thank you so much for your help! <3

Comment: Yes what you're saying is correct. The `WM_KEYDOWN` is never going to generate a _combo_ of Control.Left. You will get one event for CONTROL and another for LeftArrow. Fortunately, there's a static member of `Control.ModifierKeys` that always tells you the combination of Control-Alt-Shift at the moment. The trick is to **or** that value when you check the key. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: In the example, the handler is added in `onControlRight` in the line `button.Click += onAnyButtonClick;` Anyway, thx for accepting the answer, good luck and have fun playing around with it!